# Setting a core data entity attribute via another entity attribute

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, core-data

Is it possible to set an entity's attribute from another entity attribute?

say i have

```
entity1.attribute1 = entity2.attribute2;
```

Could this work? or is there a better practice? I have been interested in relationships, but im not sure if this would be the type of thing i need to learn at this point? Thank You for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no problem with that, it should work just fine.

Comment: Awesome, it worked perfect. I just wanted to make sure before i went and changed my model and code :) thanks!